# "This certificate is not yet valid" error on Mac

Tags: macos, installation, certificate

I have all my mac app developer certificates valid and expiring in 2019. After code signing the application and the installer pack, users would get a this: "app name was signed with a certificate that has expired. If you acquired this message recently, it may not be authentic. Do you want to continue".

Upon clicking show certificate, it says that the certificate expires in 2019 and below that "This certificate is not yet valid."

I found very little information from others with this error. And I have tried setting the date and time perfectly and it still didn't work.

Comment: What is the valid from date of the certificate?

Answer (score 19):

Often when you see this "not yet valid" error, it is because the date / time on your Mac is set incorrectly.  I do not believe that Apple lets you future date certificates (I could be wrong), so for a certificate to truly be not yet valid, it probably means that the Mac's date is set in the past.

I just walked a developer through this issue today and it was because his Mac's date was wrong. I hope this answer may help others in the future, despite being way after the original question.